# Where can I submit release codename suggestions

Tags: release-management

I want to submit a ubuntu release codename... where can I do this at? I went to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames to try and submit an idea but there isn't any location there to do so...

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you have to have the rights to edit the wiki by earning enough rep here, but I'm not too sure.

Comment: it would also be nice if people who suggested code names have their suggestion (wiki or not) posted as proof that they actually used someone's suggestion... from what i gather, they decide, and suggestions are more of a way to help them be creative and figure it out for themselves, i doubt they actually use any one suggestion, at least i've never seen it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are release codenames chosen?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/982/how-are-release-codenames-chosen)

Answer (score 5):

It is in this section:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames#Code_Name_Suggestions

Make an account for the wiki and then you can edit the page to add your own suggestion