# What will happen when there are no more letters in the alphabet for Ubuntu codenames?

Tags: release-management

[I know how codenames are chosen](https://askubuntu.com/q/982/169736). [I know where I can submit codenames](https://askubuntu.com/q/206061/169736). What I don't know is what will happen in 4 years from now (if my maths aren't that bad, 2017) when there are no more letters in the alphabet for the codenames. Will it goes backwards (ie. XYZYXW)? Will start over from A? Will use combinations (AB, AC, AD...), like **A**mourous **B**osnians?

Did anyone get a wind of this?

Comment: I suppose that is part if the nomination process for code names, people will make suggestions and one will be chosen.

Comment: It will rewind (unless the community changes its mind). Read [DevelopmentCodeNames](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames).