# What is Ubuntu's *-series?

Tags: release-management

I read that *u-series* Ubuntu release that will be delivered in October 2014, designated 14.10 is *not derived from another series*. What is this *u-series* and what are the other series? Is there going to be a major change in the kernel architecture or something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At this time there is no [release codename](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames) for Ubuntu 14.10 yet but following tradition after the Trusty Tahr (which was the "T"-series) there will be a codename with letters "U", hence the interim name *"u-series"*.

Also see: [How are release codenames chosen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982/how-are-release-codenames-chosen)

It would be rather speculative to say which changes will actually land in the 14.10. release but it appears that [Mir will be replacing X-Server](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-November/037820.html), we will see [Unity 8](https://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity8/), and [Covergence](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/CoreApps/Convergence) there.