# Why does Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr use sheep as emblem?

Tags: 14.04, login-screen, logo, branding

I have a very unimportant question: I am curious, why does Ubuntu 14.04 use sheep as emblem? Why not an elephant or ant or another animal?

Comment: @EliahKagan the artwork is derived from the name - explaining the selection of the name explains the artwork. (Look at the second question - why not ant/elephant/something else?)

Comment: @muru Here the OP knows that the name is "Trusty Tahr" and is still asking why a sheep-like emblem is shown. The answer to this question explains the connection between that image and the codename. In contrast [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/982/how-are-release-codenames-chosen) explains how the codenames are chosen. I think there is really little if any overlap between these two questions.

Comment: @EliahKagan OP probably doesn't know what a Tahr is. Explaining the name selection shows that the second part is an animal - and Googling Tahr solves the rest.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, two fundamentally different questions. It might be a bit silly, but that's ok.

Comment: @Seth I'm not convinced, but that's why we require 5 votes.

Answer (score 8):

A [Tahr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tahr) is a hardened mountain goat living in the high frozen mountains. That is whats being used as the logo - which you might mistake for a sheep.